# C# Serial Number Across Mutliple .txt files

Tags: c#

i'm learning C#. And i'm currently making a store.
A user has the option too had products too a shopping cart, and when the user pays it'll be saved down to a text file. But I would like too have every Receipt with a 'serial number' right now a receipt looks like this.

```
Receipt: #0 2020-09-19
--------------------------
Receipt: #0 2020-09-19
--------------------------
```

And they're saved too a file called Receipt_TODAYSDATE, so if I were too create a new file tomorrow it would be called Receipt_2020-09-20, and so on.
But I would like a serial number across all my receipts, so if my first receipt has the numbers, 1,2,3,4 then I would like for the other receipt too start at 5.

Not sure how I should approach and do this, I guess I could just save all the numbers down to a seperate file called SerialNumbers or something like that, and then just check what the last number is. But I would like too accomplish this without having too create more textfiles then I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few solutions for this.

### 1. Use Guid instead of serial number

Use `Guid.NewGuid()` to generate a unique identifier. One advantage is that you don't need to keep track of previous numbers using this.

### 2. Read the last number from the last receipt file

If you have access to all your files, you can parse their name to find out which is the latest one. Once you have it, you can open it, retrieve the latest serial number, and increment from there.

#### Edit:

Considering that your file has the following content.

```
Receipt: #1, Receipt: #2, Receipt: #3
```

You can find the last number using this code.

```cs
string fileContent = "Receipt: #1, Receipt: #2, Receipt: #3";
int lastNumber = int.Parse(fileContent.Split('#').Last());
Debug.WriteLine(lastNumber);
```

In this case the output is `3`. From there you can just increment that number.

Comment: Thank you, I decided too go with the last approach and find the last receipt file. How ever, now i'm stuck. How can I find the last "Receipt: #0" in the file, as a Date can contain more then 1 receipt.

Comment: How do you write your numbers in the file? I can edit my answer if you tell me how your text file is structured.

Comment: Like so: Receipt: #1, Receipt: #2, Receipt: #3 and so on.
What I tried now is just finding the index of the last # and then +1 on that index and find the number. How ever, then there is an issue if my number would be for instance 10.

Comment: I've added code sample to get the last number from the file content you provided. (It will work even with numbers containing 2 or more digits.)

Comment: I was a bit unlcear, I have some more text after Receipt: #3. so that would not work for me. How ever, I worked it out. I just find the last index of '#' and then just substring it from there. and then split at ' ' and then the first entry will be my number. Might not be the best approach too solve this, but that's how I did it.